# If the set of MIPS instructions were changed to accommodate 128 records theory question

Tags: theory, 32-bit

If the set of MIPS instructions were changed to accommodate 128 records and 4 times more instructions type-I, which would be the largest hexadecimal immediate value that could be supported, keeping the 32-bit instructions?

Comment: What are records?  Do you perhaps mean registers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean registers not records:

Most of what you're asking about is a matter of encodings which are done with bits.

4x more means 2 more bits are needed, because log<sub>2</sub>(4) = 2, or in other words, 4 = 2<sup>**2**</sup>.

The current Type-I instructions:

> I instructions are converted into machine code words in the following format:
>
> ```
> opcode  rs         rt   IMM
> 6 bits  5 bits  5 bits  16 bits
> ```

The current register fields are 5 bits which can accommodate designation of 2<sup>5</sup> = 32 different registers.  To take that to 128 registers, you'd need log<sub>2</sub>(128) = 7 (also that 2<sup>7</sup> = 128) bits, meaning 2 more bits than now.

So in total:

```
4x more opcodes:   2 more bits are needed.
4x more registers: 2 more bits are needed per register field for a total of 4 more bits
```

That all adds up to 6 more bits required, which would leave 10 bits left for the immediate field instead of the current 16.

10 bits can be used to represent an unsigned range from 0 to 2<sup>10</sup>-1 or from 0 to 1023.  Or 10 bits can be used to represent a signed range from -2<sup>9</sup> to +2<sup>9</sup>-1, or -512 to 511.  There are other encodings possible (one's complement, or, say ranging, from 1 to 1024), but there are only 2<sup>10</sup> = 1024 possible values that can be differentiated in 10 bits.

---

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new to all of "this" and sometimes questions like these can feel overwhelming.